# Show create table on a Hive Table in Spark SQL - Treats CHAR, VARCHAR as STRING

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a need to generate DDL statements for Hive tables & views programmatically. I tried using Spark and Beeline for this task. Beeline takes around 5-10 seconds for each of the statements whereas Spark completes the same thing in a few milliseconds. I am planning to use Spark since it is faster compared to beeline. One downside of using spark for getting DDL statements from the hive is, it treats CHAR, VARCHAR characters as String and it doesn't preserve the length information that goes with CHAR,VARCHAR data types. At the same time beeline preserves the data type and the length information for CHAR,VARCHAR data types. I am using Spark 2.4.1 and Beeline 2.1.1.

Given below the sample create table command and its show create table output.

**Beeline Output:**

[image]

**Spark-Shell:**

[image]

I wanted to know if there is any configuration on the Spark side to preserve the data type and length information for CHAR,VARCHAR data types. If there are other ways to get DDL from Hive quickly, I will be fine with that also.

Comment: Beware that depending in your versions, the DDL commands are different in Hive and Spark.

Answer (score 1):

This is in

```
Hive 3.1.1
Spark 3.1.1
```

Your stack overflow issue raised and I quote:

"I have a need to generate DDL statements for Hive tables & views programmatically. I tried using Spark and Beeline for this task. Beeline takes around 5-10 seconds for each of the statements whereas Spark completes the same thing in a few milliseconds. I am planning to use Spark since it is faster compared to beeline. One downside of using spark for getting DDL statements from the hive is, it treats CHAR, VARCHAR characters as String and it doesn't preserve the length information that goes with CHAR,VARCHAR data types. At the same time beeline preserves the data type and the length information for CHAR,VARCHAR data types. I am using Spark 2.4.1 and Beeline 2.1.1. Given below the sample create table command and its show create table output."

Create a simple table in Hive in test database

```
hive> use test;
OK
hive> create table etc(ID BIGINT, col1 VARCHAR(30), col2 STRING);
OK
hive> desc formatted etc;
# col_name              data_type               comment
id                      bigint
col1                    varchar(30)
col2                    string

# Detailed Table Information
Database:               test
OwnerType:              USER
Owner:                  hduser
CreateTime:             Fri Mar 11 18:29:34 GMT 2022
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Retention:              0
Location:               hdfs://rhes75:9000/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/etc
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE
Table Parameters:
        COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   {\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\",\"COLUMN_STATS\":{\"col1\":\"true\",\"col2\":\"true\",\"id\":\"true\"}}
        bucketing_version       2
        numFiles                0
        numRows                 0
        rawDataSize             0
        totalSize               0
        transient_lastDdlTime   1647023374

# Storage Information
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
        serialization.format    1
```

Now let's go to spark-shell

```
scala> spark.sql("show create table test.etc").show(false)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|createtab_stmt                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CREATE TABLE `test`.`etc` (
  `id` BIGINT,
  `col1` VARCHAR(30),
  `col2` STRING)
USING text
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'bucketing_version' = '2',
  'transient_lastDdlTime' = '1647023374')
|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can see Spark shows columns correctly

Now let us go and create the same table in hive through beeline

```
0: jdbc:hive2://rhes75:10099/default> use test

No rows affected (0.019 seconds)


0: jdbc:hive2://rhes75:10099/default> create table etc(ID BIGINT, col1 VARCHAR(30), col2 STRING)

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . > No rows affected (0.304 seconds)

0: jdbc:hive2://rhes75:10099/default> desc formatted etc

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . > +-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+

|           col_name            |                     data_type                      |                      comment                       |

+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+

| # col_name                    | data_type                                          | comment                                            |

| id                            | bigint                                             |                                                    |

| col1                          | varchar(30)                                        |                                                    |

| col2                          | string                                             |                                                    |

|                               | NULL                                               | NULL                                               |

| # Detailed Table Information  | NULL                                               | NULL                                               |

| Database:                     | test                                               | NULL                                               |

| OwnerType:                    | USER                                               | NULL                                               |

| Owner:                        | hduser                                             | NULL                                               |

| CreateTime:                   | Fri Mar 11 18:51:00 GMT 2022                       | NULL                                               |

| LastAccessTime:               | UNKNOWN                                            | NULL                                               |

| Retention:                    | 0                                                  | NULL                                               |

| Location:                     | hdfs://rhes75:9000/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/etc | NULL                                               |

| Table Type:                   | MANAGED_TABLE                                      | NULL                                               |

| Table Parameters:             | NULL                                               | NULL                                               |

|                               | COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE                              | {\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\",\"COLUMN_STATS\":{\"col1\":\"true\",\"col2\":\"true\",\"id\":\"true\"}} |

|                               | bucketing_version                                  | 2                                                  |

|                               | numFiles                                           | 0                                                  |

|                               | numRows                                            | 0                                                  |

|                               | rawDataSize                                        | 0                                                  |

|                               | totalSize                                          | 0                                                  |

|                               | transient_lastDdlTime                              | 1647024660                                         |

|                               | NULL                                               | NULL                                               |

| # Storage Information         | NULL                                               | NULL                                               |

| SerDe Library:                | org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe | NULL                                               |

| InputFormat:                  | org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat           | NULL                                               |

| OutputFormat:                 | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat | NULL                                               |

| Compressed:                   | No                                                 | NULL                                               |

| Num Buckets:                  | -1                                                 | NULL                                               |

| Bucket Columns:               | []                                                 | NULL                                               |

| Sort Columns:                 | []                                                 | NULL                                               |

| Storage Desc Params:          | NULL                                               | NULL                                               |

|                               | serialization.format                               | 1                                                  |

+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+

33 rows selected (0.159 seconds)
```

Now check that in spark-shell again

```
scala> spark.sql("show create table test.etc").show(false)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

|createtab_stmt                                                                                                                                                                      |

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

|CREATE TABLE `test`.`etc` (

  `id` BIGINT,

  `col1` VARCHAR(30),

  `col2` STRING)

USING text

TBLPROPERTIES (

  'bucketing_version' = '2',

  'transient_lastDdlTime' = '1647024660')

|

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It shows OK.  So in summary you get column definitions in Spark as you have defined them in Hive.

In your statement above and I quote "I am using Spark 2.4.1 and Beeline 2.1.1", refers to older versions of Spark and hive which may have had such issues.

Comment: Thank you @Mich Talebzadeh for your answer. Its good to know that VARCHAR and CHAR are properly showing in Spark 3. Do you know what changed in Spark 3 that made this possible?. Or how can I achieve the same output in Spark 2.4.1. If there are some conf options, that would be helpful.